# Crashlytics - EXC_BAD_ACCESS WebKitLegacy crash ios

Tags: ios, swift, native, crashlytics, google-fabric

There are many crashes reported for WebKitLegacy on Crashlytics and I have been using webview in my application. There is no way to figure out why these crashes occur. I have set the delegate and webview to nil in viewwilldisappear method. But still it is crashing. Can please someone help me in this?
[[image: Crashlytics Report[1]]

Answer (score 3):

This error might be misleading. Are you using NSAttributedString to load HTML or to display "web link" like button? If so you might be calling the HTML importer from a background thread. See details here:

[Unable to reproduce WebKitLegacy -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712772/unable-to-reproduce-webkitlegacy-websafeforwarder-forwardinvocation-crash)